# How to get Indeterminate Checkbox to fire function of other checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I made a table that has checkboxes that show and hide rows to make it easier to compare specific rows. I wanted to add indeterminate checkboxes so that multiple rows can be selected or not selected at the same time. It kinda works in that it checks the boxes under it but doesn't fire the function to hide or show the row even though its checked. The individual check boxes still fire the function though.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jta1/sv59w5m2/)

Show/hide rows with checkbox

```
$('input[type = checkbox]').change(function () {
var valu = $(this).val();
var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");

if( ischecked ){
    $('.' + valu).show();
}else{
    $('.' + valu).hide();
}
});
```

Indeterminate Checkbox for division 1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.div1'),
checkdiv1 = document.getElementById('checkdiv1');

for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
    var checkedCount = document.querySelectorAll('input.div1:checked').length;

    checkdiv1.checked = checkedCount > 0;
    checkdiv1.indeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < checkboxes.length;
}
}

checkdiv1.onclick = function() {
for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
}
}
});
```

Indeterminate Checkbox for division 2

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.div2'),
checkdiv2 = document.getElementById('checkdiv2');

for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
    var checkedCount = document.querySelectorAll('input.div2:checked').length;

    checkdiv2.checked = checkedCount > 0;
    checkdiv2.indeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < checkboxes.length;
}
}

checkdiv2.onclick = function() {
for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
}
}
});
```

Comment: If one of our answers has helped you, please select one of them as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to add hide/show rows based on inner check boxes, so you can bind 'change' event handler to check boxes with class "show". So, you code would be

```
$('input[type = checkbox].show').change(function () {
```

instead of

```
$('input[type = checkbox]').change(function () {
```

2) You can remove second $(document).ready() function and combine your code into one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ fun1() });
$(document).ready(function(){ fun2() });
```

is equivalent to

```
$(document).ready(function(){ fun1(); fun2(); });
```

3) You can trigger 'change' event of inner check boxes when outer check box is clicked:

```
$(checkboxes[i]).trigger('change');
```

```js
$('input[type = checkbox].show').change(function () {
    
    var valu = $(this).val();
    var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");
    
    if( ischecked ){
        $('.' + valu).show();
    }else{
        $('.' + valu).hide();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
   var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.div1');
    var checkdiv1 = document.getElementById('checkdiv1');

    for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
            var checkedCount = document.querySelectorAll('input.div1:checked').length;

            checkdiv1.checked = checkedCount > 0;
            checkdiv1.indeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < checkboxes.length;
        }
    }

    checkdiv1.onclick = function() {
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.div1');
        for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = this.checked;        
            $(checkboxes[i]).trigger('change');
        }
    }

   var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.div2');
    var checkdiv2 = document.getElementById('checkdiv2');

    for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
            var checkedCount = document.querySelectorAll('input.div2:checked').length;

            checkdiv2.checked = checkedCount > 0;
            checkdiv2.indeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < checkboxes.length;
        }
    }

    checkdiv2.onclick = function() {
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.div2');
        for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
            $(checkboxes[i]).trigger('change');
        }
    }
    
    $('.hideRow').click(function () {
        $('input[value="' + $(this).attr('checkBoxValue') + '"]').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

```css
.hide{
    visibility: hidden;
}

label {
    display:block
}

label:first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
}

label:nth-child(n+2) {
    margin-left:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkdiv1" checked> Division 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="div1 show" value="d1" checked> Team 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="div1 show" value="d2" checked > Team 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="div1 show" value="d3" checked> Team 3</label></div>
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="checkdiv2" checked> Division 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="div2 show" value="r1" checked> Team 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="div2 show" value="r2" checked > Team 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="div2 show" value="r3" checked> Team 3</label></div>
<br>
<hr>
    
<br>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
     <tr>            
            <td></td>
            <td >Teams</td>
            <td>Points For</td>
            <td>Points Against</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d1">
            <td><button class="hideRow" checkBoxValue="d1">Hide</button></td>
            <td>Division 1 Team 1</td>
            <td>280</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d2">
            <td><button class="hideRow" checkBoxValue="d2">Hide</button></td>
            <td>Division 1 Team 2</td>
            <td>225</td>
            <td>150</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d3">
            <td><button class="hideRow" checkBoxValue="d3">Hide</button></td>
            <td>Division 1 Team 3</td>
            <td>187</td>
            <td>223</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="r1">
            <td><button class="hideRow" checkBoxValue="r1">Hide</button></td>
            <td>Division 2 Team 1</td>
            <td>330</td>
            <td>185</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="r2">
            <td><button class="hideRow" checkBoxValue="r2">Hide</button></td>
            <td>Division 2 Team 2</td>
            <td>267</td>
            <td>225</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="r3">
            <td><button class="hideRow" checkBoxValue="r3">Hide</button></td>
            <td>Division 2 Team 3</td>
            <td>223</td>
            <td>150</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Chitrang, I was wondering if you could help me with one more thing. I want to add a button in the first column of each row that would hide that specific row in addition to unchecking that corresponding check box at the top.

Comment: Updated the answer to add button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of this in your change handler. You'll have to rethink your markup to a small degree but it's pretty simple. I added `data-target` and `data-nodes` to the parent checkboxes, and `d` and `r` classes to the table rows.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-target="d" data-nodes=".div1" checked>Division 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="div1 show" value="d1" checked>Team 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="div1 show" value="d2" checked>Team 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="div1 show" value="d3" checked>Team 3</label>
</div>
<div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-target="r" data-nodes=".div2"  checked>Division 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="div2 show" value="r1" checked>Team 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="div2 show" value="r2" checked>Team 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="div2 show" value="r3" checked>Team 3</label>
</div>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Teams</td>
            <td>Points For</td>
            <td>Points Against</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d d1">
            <td>Division 1 Team 1</td>
            <td>280</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d d2">
            <td>Division 1 Team 2</td>
            <td>225</td>
            <td>150</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d d3">
            <td>Division 1 Team 3</td>
            <td>187</td>
            <td>223</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="r r1">
            <td>Division 2 Team 1</td>
            <td>330</td>
            <td>185</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="r r2">
            <td>Division 2 Team 2</td>
            <td>267</td>
            <td>225</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="r r3">
            <td>Division 2 Team 3</td>
            <td>223</td>
            <td>150</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type = checkbox]').change(function () {
    var nodes = $(this).data("nodes");
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    var valu = $(this).val();
    var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");

    // If the nodes data attribute exists, use its value
    if (target) {
        valu = target;
    }

    if (ischecked) {
        $('.' + valu).show();
        $(nodes).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('.' + valu).hide();
        $(nodes).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sv59w5m2/2/